# Ошибка определения свойства Vue

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть компонент. У него есть props - `searchString`. Если обновить локальное свойство и использовать его в `v-model`

```
data: {
    localSearchString: this.searchString
}
```

то ошибки нету, но с компонента, где вызывается этот компонент, я не могу изменить это свойство. А если не указать локального, а только props - тогда изменяется, но получаю ошибку

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, вы пытаетесь изменить значение входящего пропса, так делать нерекомендуется

Логика проста, ваш компонент должен иметь двусторонюю привязку данных

Делается это просто:
Там где у вас вызывается компонент вы используете

```
<v-component
:current-param.sync="currentValue"
>
```

В самом компоненте получаете его как props

```
props: {
  currentParam: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
```

На самом элементе вы используете пропс как `v-model`
Также вам надо отслеживать событие и делать эмит его "Наверх"
в данном случае это `@change`

```
<input type="text"
  v-model="currentParam"
  @change="$emit('update:current-param', currentParam)"
>
```

Таким образом оба компонента, родительский и дочерний будут иметь общие реактивные данные